# Bootstrap Popover Element Inside A-Link; Prevent A-Link Click From Firing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Popover Image which should display a popup. This IMG is inside an A-link which has its own Click Handler.

My goal is to prevent the Parent A-Click from firing; when you click the image, the only thing you see is the popup, but not the real A-Click action (the alert box).

I know that this is done via `e.stopPropagation()` but the problem is, how do I get access to Bootstrap Popover's Click Handler? Where would I put `e.stopPropagation`?

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

$('#link').off('click.link').on('click.link', function() {
    alert('Clicked main link');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<a id="link" href="#" style="width:300px; height:100px; border:1px solid black;">Main Link

<img src="abc.png" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="" data-content="PopOver Tooltip" aria-describedby="tooltip">
</a>
```

Let me show why the IMG has to be inside the A. The A's are Accordion Menu Bars, and they all have a fixed width. You can go to a page by selecting a menu (you don't have to click right on the text). Some menu items also have an INFO I icon that displays a popup. The action of the I-Icon should be to display the popover. The action of the A-link itself should be to go the page as normal.
[image]

Comment: Your anchor provides zero functionality based on the above code; as you note it doesn't link anywhere, it also doesn't provide any necessary purpose.  I would ask the obvious; why bother using it at all if its use necessitates you use JavaScript to bypass its base function?

Comment: The answer is, the links are Menu Items, and they also have an Info icon next to the title. Sometimes the user can click the Info icon to see what the menu is about, and will get a tooltip, before actually selecting the menu. Does this make sense?

Comment: b - But if their `href` value is always `#` you could avoid this entire issue by simply using a different element like `<button>`

Comment: @RobertC bootstrap may not provide the styling he needs for a `<button>`, it may only work an anchor element.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Bootstrap doesn't care what element you use in this sort of instance.

Comment: Guys I solved it -- see my answer. e.preventDefault() and checking e.target.nodeName is not IMG.

Comment: @RobertC for example, you can't create a button on a navbar, if you do it doesn't look right. [JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/erikphilips/y1pzkwx9/)... please do research before making a comment like that.

Answer (score 0):

Per our conversation in the comments I believe there are superior alternatives to relying on an anchor element to achieve this and would encourage you to explore alternatives like `<button>` since the purpose of this item seems to be better suited for that element.

That being said, to address the question at hand:

If you add a class to your anchor element so that you can target it via JavaScript your solution is quite simple:

```
$('a.poplink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will prevent any anchor element with the class of `poplink` from processing a click-through event, without prohibiting the Bootstrap Popover event tied to your `<img>`.

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

$('a.poplink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a id="link" href="http://google.com" class="poplink" style="width:300px; height:100px; border:1px solid black;">
  Main Link
  <img src="abc.png" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="" data-content="PopOver Tooltip" aria-describedby="tooltip">
</a>
```

Comment: But this lost the action from the link, which was an alert box. The A-link by itself has a separate action, and it should be kept. The IMG by itself should display the popover.

Comment: Then you will need to separate the two items. The `alert` is always going to fire whether you click `Main Link` or just on the `img` as both are part of `<a>...</a>`

Comment: Robert -- I uploaded a pic in my original post to show why I need this. The menu items have a fixed width. I can't just click on the text span itself, the menu is the whole bar. But sometimes it has an I-icon that has the popover.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it...

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

$('#link').off('click.link').on('click.link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.nodeName != "IMG") {
      alert('Clicked main link');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<a id="link" href="#" style="width:300px; height:100px; border:1px solid black;">Main Link

<img src="abc.png" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="" data-content="PopOver Tooltip" aria-describedby="tooltip">
</a>
```